# Why char s [5] doesn't collect value correctly?

Tags: c

This is my simple program:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s [5] = "Hello";
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

`Hello` is a 5 chars length so I define a `char s [5]` but the output is:

> Hellop\370\277_\377

And when I change the `char s [5]` to `char s []`, everything works fine. What's the problem with my code?

Comment: You forgot the place for the 0-terminator, `"Hello"` needs 6 bytes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're forgetting the null terminator.

C strings are expected to have one `\0` byte on the end to mark the end of the string. The reason your output looks strange is because `printf`, looking for the null terminator, has wandered off into uninitialized memory, which triggers undefined behavior.

In this case, `printf` appears to somewhat luckily find a null pretty quickly, and terminate normally after printing some garbage. However, this kind of bug will often crash your program with the message `segmentation fault`. A "seg fault" occurs when the operating system kills your process because it's doing something it's not supposed to, like reading memory that doesn't belong to it.

Try this instead:

```
char s[] = "Hello"; //s is now 6 characters long.
```

By not providing a number, the compiler decides how big your array needs to be and copies the `"Hello"` data into it.

If you need a string you don't want to change, you should declare them this way instead:

```
const char* s = "Hello";
```

This way, you've created a pointer that points to static memory, containing the string `"Hello"`, no copy needed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in C. Didn't know that! Thanks :)

Comment: There is no need to use the declaration shown at the end of this answer, making `s` a pointer to const char. The array is fine. If it is visibly not modified, or if the declaration is changed to `const char s[] = …`, then the compiler should put it in the same read-only segment that a literal string would be placed in.