# why my program doesn't tell that the last charcter of the string array is a NULL?

Tags: c, arrays, null

i think that every string array ends with a NULL charcter but in thiss program the statment of checking if the last charcter of the string array is not True

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

char hey[5]="hello";


if(hey[5] == NULL){
    puts("Yes the last charcter is a NULL ");
}

return 0;

}
```

and also if NULL is \0  why when i try if (NULL == "\0") the statement is always False ?

Comment: This question has been closed for the wrong reason! The problem is that the `hey` array is not long enough ("hello" requires an array of at least **six** elements).

Comment: BTW `NULL == '\0'` in most C implementations

Comment: @AdrianMole it is closed for the *right* reason, i.e. it is a duplicate.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, now that I can see the list of **all** duplicates, I agree. On my first look, they weren't all there.

Comment: @AdrianMole yes, because I hammered it and then edited the duplicates as my hammer privilege.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks so much for the help i changed to 6 and it worked but why does hello array use six elements when it is 0 based

Comment: 5 (visible) letters **plus** the nul-terminator character.

Comment: @OussemaNehdi `h` , `e`, `l`, `l`, `o`, `\0`  - count them

Comment: @OussemaNehdi please read [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489272/why-char-s-5-doesnt-collect-value-correctly) that I marked this question as a duplicate of.

Comment: @anastaciu elaborate.

Comment: NULL converts to zero

Comment: `NULL == '\0'` is always true (1) and correct and whatnot. But you cannot portably use `c[i] == NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your string is too short and the initialization copies only 5 chars. The `hey[5]` (6th element of the array) is past the array bounds and  is not determined

```
char hey[]="hello";

if(hey[5] == '\0'  /* or simply 0 */){
    puts("Yes the last character is a nul terminator");
}
```

2. NULL is not a nul terminator.